# Could not find class 'org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver' error while running selenium script

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium

Getting this error while running demo script, is there any workaround for this issue?

Could not find class 'org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver' ..........

IDE: Eclipse

OS: Windows 7 -- 64 bit

SDK Manager: 22.3

Android SDK build tool: 19

Selenium java: selenium-2.37.0

1. Did the setup as mentioned in the link
   https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver?ts=1318649352&updated=AndroidDriver#Install_the_APK
2. Added the selenium java jar file to the build path

I found one open issue which is open from 1 year
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3077

Answer (score 0):

Running the script in a java project is the soultion